# Trying to find a word in a string full text search sqlite

Tags: sqlite, search

Hi I have a string which is a question for example: Where is the van ?

I have enabled Full Text search on sqlite

I have tried this:

```
String sql = "Select * from tblzh20 WHERE tblzh20 MATCH '" + question + "'";
```

however nothing is returned unless I just put van as the question!

I'm trying to search the table for keywords within the question and find the results? I'm sure this is possible but not sure how.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
"Select * from tblzh20 WHERE tblzh20 MATCH '{keyword objective}:" + question + "'";
```